# Oracle date function for the previous month

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-date-functions

I have the query below where the date is hard-coded. My objective is to remove the harcoded date; the query should pull the data for the previous month when it runs.

```
select count(distinct switch_id)
  from xx_new.xx_cti_call_details@appsread.prd.com
 where dealer_name =  'XXXX'
   and TRUNC(CREATION_DATE) BETWEEN '01-AUG-2012' AND '31-AUG-2012'
```

Should I use `sysdate-15` function for that?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Modifying Ben's query little bit,

```
 select count(distinct switch_id)   
  from xx_new.xx_cti_call_details@appsread.prd.com  
 where dealer_name =  'XXXX'    
   and creation_date between add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1) and last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1))
```

Comment: Yes, trunc('mm') and last_day() is exactly what you want :)

Comment: Using last_day() and trunc() will give you the beginning of the last day though, is that what you want?  For me, it gave me last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1)) gave me July 31 2015, 00:00:00.  If I use that with between, I'm missing out on all data from July 31st.

Comment: i like your code its superb and end of my searching in same topic.

Comment: maybe the condition can be optimized:
and trunc(creation_date, 'mm') = add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'), -1)

Comment: @BoydDensmore Unfortunately, the answer *does* miss out all the data from the last day of the month. However, it is a *very* simple matter to fix by using the plus operator to add 1 in order to get the beginning of the first day of the next month, like so: `(last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1))+1)`.

Answer (score 16):

The [`trunc()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php) function truncates a date to the specified time period; so `trunc(sysdate,'mm')` would return the beginning of the current month. You can then use the [`add_months()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/add_months.php) function to get the beginning of the previous month, something like this:

```
select count(distinct switch_id)   
  from xx_new.xx_cti_call_details@appsread.prd.com  
 where dealer_name =  'XXXX'    
   and creation_date >= add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1) 
   and creation_date < trunc(sysdate, 'mm')
```

As a little side not you're not *explicitly* converting to a date in your original query. *Always* do this, either using a [date literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm), e.g. `DATE 2012-08-31`, or the [`to_date()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) function, for example `to_date('2012-08-31','YYYY-MM-DD')`. If you don't then you are bound to get this wrong at some point.

You would not use `sysdate - 15` as this would provide the date 15 days before the current date, which does not seem to be what you are after. It would also include a time component as you are not using `trunc()`.

---

Just as a little demonstration of what `trunc(<date>,'mm')` does:

```
select sysdate
     , case when trunc(sysdate,'mm') > to_date('20120901 00:00:00','yyyymmdd hh24:mi:ss')
             then 1 end as gt
     , case when trunc(sysdate,'mm') < to_date('20120901 00:00:00','yyyymmdd hh24:mi:ss')
             then 1 end as lt
     , case when trunc(sysdate,'mm') = to_date('20120901 00:00:00','yyyymmdd hh24:mi:ss')
             then 1 end as eq
  from dual
       ;

SYSDATE                   GT         LT         EQ
----------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
20120911 19:58:51                                1
```

Comment: Thanks Ben , but above function is giving me data for sep 1st as well.

Comment: It's not :-), `select * from dual where trunc(sysdate,'mm') > to_date('20120901 00:00:00','yyyymmdd hh24:mi:ss')`. The date given is such that it will only allow anything _before_ the first of September.

Comment: I see 18 recs of 9/1/2012.  Thanks

Comment: @user803860, I've update the query, which should get rid of the problem you're having. It explicitly states that the `created` date should be less than 2012-09-01 00:00:00.

Comment: But in the qry it is harcoding for sep, i have to run it every month for previous month .

Comment: @user803860, there is no hard-coding; the top-query will in September, return everything for August and in October return everything for September. I don't hard-code a date at all.

Answer (score 3):

Data for last month-

```
select count(distinct switch_id)
  from xx_new.xx_cti_call_details@appsread.prd.com
 where dealer_name =  'XXXX'
   and to_char(CREATION_DATE,'MMYYYY') = to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate),-1),'MMYYYY');
```

Comment: I don't think you need TO_CHAR() here ... and might using TRUNC() bypass the index on the column (if there is one)?

Comment: I do need `to_char` to get the Month `MM` and `trunc` is to discard any `timestamp` component. Also, use of any function disables the use of indexes i.e. `to_char`, `trunc`, `to_date`, but if performance is a concern then a Function Based index can be created. I the case above, i may skip `trunc` anyways since I already use `to_char` but it doesn't hurt.

Comment: You can specify an 'MM' mask in TRUNC() to avoid using TO_CHAR() ... I think using TO_CHAR() would also pull previous years' records.

Comment: well, using `trunc(date,'MM')` will return you the first day of the month and not just the month i.e. it will return `01-SEP-2012` and not `SEP` or `09`, and then you have to do a `between` in the where clause and so on. The way I said is just a quick and easy way of doing it and very understandable too. And to the year point, I have edited my answer to include 'YYYY'.

Comment: Yes, `TRUNC(date, 'MM')` will return the first day of the month - so will `ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate, 'MM'), -1)` so one can check for equality.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this would also work:

```
select count(distinct switch_id)   
  from xx_new.xx_cti_call_details@appsread.prd.com  
 where 
   dealer_name =  'XXXX'    
   and (creation_date BETWEEN add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'),-1) and  trunc(sysdate, 'mm'))
```

It has the advantage of using *BETWEEN* which is the way the OP used his date selection criteria.

Comment: This was a cleaner way to go for me.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It is working with me in Oracle sql developer

```
    SELECT add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'), -1),
           last_day(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'mm'), -1)) 
    FROM dual
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting last nth months data retrieve

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE DATE_COLUMN BETWEEN '&STARTDATE' AND '&ENDDATE';
```